# HP DL360G7 disk swap different cpu

Tags: hp

I have a broken DL360G7 with a E5-5620 2.4GHz CPU.

Can i take the HDDs of the broken one and place them into another DL360G7 but with a faster CPU (X5670 2.93GHz), and expect everything to work again?
Except the CPU, everything else is the same.

Comment: Yes, you can - given that the second system does have the same (RAID) controller(s) with compatible (better: the same) firmwares.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The RAID configuration is stored on the disks, not the controller.

Be sure to keep the disks in the same order/position between machines.

Comment: So the CPU does not matter at all?